# Soap service response not being sent in Wildlfy 9.0.2 and CXF 3.0.1 environment

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, wildfly, wildfly-9

We have a soap service which is built on CXF 3.0.1 using java and it is deployed in Wildlfy 9.0.2. The code uses its own CXF jars and does not use the Wildfly provides CXF module.

There is a client which consumes this service. The client code also uses CXF 3.0.1 coupled with SAAJ and is deployed in a Weblogic 12 instance.

The issue is that when the client invokes this service the request is received in Wildfly, the process finishes, but no response is generated (in CXF logs) or sent back to the client.

When I inspect the TCP packets I realize the client call has the following headers:

> Encoding: UTF-8 Http-Method: POST Content-Type: text/xml;
>   charset=UTF-8 Headers: {Accept=[*/*], connection=[Keep-Alive],
>   content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8],
>   Host=[ws-env.applications.services.com-tech.intra],
>   SOAPAction=["http://path to soap action"],
>   transfer-encoding=[**chunked**], User-Agent=[Apache CXF 3.0.1]}

The client call ultimately fails with the below error:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
>                   at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:148)
>                   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.processStrucutredEnvelopes(Unknown Source) ...
>   **Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException
>   invoking
>   http://endpointURL:
>   Read time out after 60000 millis**
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>                   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1359)
>                   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1343)
>                   at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>                   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:638)
>                   at

The execution of the service takes 4-5 seconds max.

The other surprising issue is that this service when invoked from SOAPUI or even a wget from the client server returns with a valid SOAP response.

I tried to set the HTTPConduit configuration as described at:https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Apache+CXF+integration#ApacheCXFintegration-HTTPConduitconfiguration but that did not seem to help.

Any help would be appreciated.